# MFC: Bug on 'Maximized Button' if the program was previously closed under the maximized state

Tags: c++, mfc, window

I am an MFC beginner. I found this little error when I created a simple Form Based MFC application (using the VS2012), but I don't know how to fix it.

The default program seems to remember the program's previous state, i.e. window position, window size (maximized or minimized). So when the program is reopened, the program will be restored to the state that it was closed last time.

Here are the steps to find the bug:

1) open the program

2) maximize the window

3) close the program

4) re-launch the program

What happened is, when I re-launch the program, although the window is not in a maximized state, the 'maximize' button at top right window does not show correctly. Instead of showing a maximized icon, it now shows a 'restore down' icon...

How do I fix this bug?

Moreover, how do I disable this function so the program can always be launched at a specific position and size, regardless its previous closing state?

Using m_pMainWnd->MoveWindow(x, y, Width, Height) function before m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);?

Comment: Most probably, you're only persisting window size and not window state. Can you post more of your code so we can confirm this?

Comment: Hi, I would like to share my code. But which part of the code shall I post?

I noticed that the same bug will appear even on the default code (without adding any modification) if one creates the project using the 'Visual Studio' project style.

Comment: I was thinking about the code that saves and restores the window dimensions. If that code is part of MFC proper, and you only call MFC functions to use it, please post the code that calls these functions.

Comment: I guess the OP thinks that there is a bug in Visual Studio, not in his code :)

Answer (score 1):

When I create a default sample with a CFormView the OnInitialUpdate contains the line **ResizeParentToFit();**

Remove it, and the application is maximized as the previous state. ResizeParentToFit, does exactly what the name says. It resizes the parent window so the parent window fits exactly the form you created.

If you don't want that the window placement is restored at all, set the variable **CWinApEx::m_bLoadWindowPlacement** to FALSE. By default this flag is set to TRUE!